# Get rid of special characters from perl string

Tags: perl

I have this string:

```
$x = \x02 . 'raz' . \x02;
```

How to clean this up to have only "raz" ?

I try this:

```
$x =~ s/^[a-zA-z0-9,]//g;
```

but I would get:

```
SCALAR0x560917295870razSCALAR0x560917295900
```

how to get just "raz"?

Comment: What do you get when you just print `$x` before your cleanup? Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: `\x02` is a string, it should be interpolated into a double quoted string, i.e. `"\x02raz\x02"`. It should not be written as an escaped bareword.

Comment: That output would not be produced by the code you posted. It would have produced `CALAR(0x560917295870)razSCALAR(0x560917295900)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the 5-character string produced by `"\x02" . 'raz' . "\x02"`, then the following would work:

```perl
$x =~ s/[^a-zA-z0-9,]//g;
```

Note how I moved the `^`.

Outside of a character class (`[...]`), it means "start of string" (or "start of line" when `/m` is used).

But as the first character of a character class (`[^...]`), it negates the character class. It will match all characters except those listed.

---

`\x02 . 'raz' . \x02`, on the other hand, produces a string of the form `SCALAR(0xXXX)razSCALAR(0xXXX)`.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'say \x02 . "raz" . \x02;'
SCALAR(0x565362191c08)razSCALAR(0x565362163750)
```

You could use

```perl
$x =~ s/SCALAR\([^()]*\)//g;
```

---

Note that you should *always* use `use strict; use warnings;`. This would have avoided the situation that lead to the garbage being created in the first place.

Comment: Updated answer.